# How to print the address of a ByteBuffer in Java?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I want to check the address of a `ByteBuffer` in Java. I googled and found [here](http://www.docjar.com/src/api/com/sun/corba/se/impl/encoding/BufferManagerReadStream.java) mentioned the address of `ByteBuffer` as following:

```
// print address of ByteBuffer being queued
int bbAddress = System.identityHashCode(byteBuffer);
```

I'm not sure, so i need someone can help me to verify.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that? Seems like a very strange use case to me. `System.identityHashCode()` might return a number that has some connection to the (virtual) memory address of the Object, but that is neither required nor guaranteed, as far as I know...

Comment: @JerikcXIONG Why do you want to do this? As Florian said, `identityHashCode` returns the default `hashCode` which may not necessarily give you the exact memory address of an object.

Comment: @CKing  I have many ByteBuffer objects, and I want to print the addresses of them to check whether the same object.

Comment: @CKing Is there any way to print the address of a ByteBuffer ?

Comment: If you have two ByteBuffer objects and want to see if they are the same object just do a byteBuffer1 == byteBuffer2 check.

Comment: You don't need the address. The HashCode is sufficient for your requirement.

Comment: @Nozdrum  I have many ByteBuffer objects.

Comment: @JerikcXIONG What are you trying to achieve. Chances are that you are asking the wrong question. What is your final objective?

Comment: @Fildor But as Florian and CKing said, identityHashCode returns the default hashCode which may not necessarily give you the exact memory address of an object. So i hope someone can provide a right way.

Comment: @CKing I don't think it's a wrong question. I just want to know how to print the address of a object for debugging.

Comment: @JerikcXIONG It's a wrong question if you want the exact address. If you are okay with a representation of the address, you can simply use hashCode.

Comment: @CKing You mean there is no way to get the exact address of it, right ? In fact, I want to get the unique information of a `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: @JerikcXIONG if you want to check whether they are the same object just compare the `hashcode`s of the two different `ByteBuffer`s.

Comment: In order to check if they are the same object, one can simply compare them with `if (b0 == b1)`. No need to go over `identityHashCode` here (and `hashCode` alone would be plainly wrong). However, I'm also pretty sure that the question suffers from the XY-Problem  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . If you wanted to obtain the *address* of a byte buffer that was allocated with `allocateDirect`, the question could actually make sense, but until now, this is a different story...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

['As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects.'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), and this applies to `System.identityHashcode()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to include a unique identifier for different objects in a log file. Then

```
System.identityHashCode(object);
```

is the way to go. In case of array it is also true that

```
System.identityHashCode(array) == array.hashCode()
```

Note that this is a unique identifer, but not a memory address like the address of a pointer in C.